# Hiding the row in the cshtml after the contents are loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two rows in my cshtml that shows amount values. The business rule that I need to implement is, if both the amounts are equal then only one row needs to be shown. I have written a code but not sure how to get it to work.

```
$(function ShowHideRow () {

            var cashAvailbleToInvestInFunds = $('#trCashAvailableToInvestInFunds').val;
            var cashAvailbleToInvestInEquities = $('#trCashAvailableToInvestInEquities').val;

            if (cashAvailbleToInvestInFunds == cashAvailbleToInvestInEquities)
                $('#trCashAvailableToInvestInEquities').hide();
        });


<tr id="trCashAvailableToInvestInFunds" >
                        <td>Available cash to Invest in funds at @date_request</td>
                        <td>@Model.CashAvailableToInvest.ToString("C")</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="trCashAvailableToInvestInEquities">
                        <td>Available cash to Invest in equities at @date_request</td>
                        <td>@Model.CashAvailableToInvestInEquities.ToString("C")</td>
                    </tr>
```

I tried writing the logic on DocumentReady but that wouldnt work as the function would fire even before the contents are loaded. Could somebody tell me how do i go about it.

Comment: If its in `document.ready` then it wont fire until the contents are loaded. A `<tr>`  does not have a value attribute so you cant use `$('#trCashAvailableToInvestInFunds').val()`. You need to get the `.text()` of the second `<td>` element in each row and compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the Razor view instead:

```
    <tr id="trCashAvailableToInvestInFunds" >
                        <td>Available cash to Invest in funds at @date_request</td>
                        <td>@Model.CashAvailableToInvest.ToString("C")</td>
                    </tr>
@if(Model.CashAvailableToInvestInEquities != Model.CashAvailableToInvest)
{
                    <tr id="trCashAvailableToInvestInEquities">
                        <td>Available cash to Invest in equities at @date_request</td>
                        <td>@Model.CashAvailableToInvestInEquities.ToString("C")</td>
                    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Doing it in razor makes sense